# How to install the "Links 2" browser in Lubuntu?

Tags: apt, software-installation, lubuntu, 16.04, browser

I went to the official website but they had this complicated list of steps where I had to manually check a bunch of dependencies and then download a tarball, only to have to follow a further list of steps, etc.

Isn't there any easier way? `apt-get`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is the package links2 in Ubuntu universe repository. To enable universe repository:

   - First way: Open `Software & Updates` and under `Ubuntu Software` tab check the box `Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)`. When you close `Software & Updates`, click reload to update the cache.
   - Second way: Run in terminal `sudo add-apt-repository universe` and then `sudo apt-get update` in order to update software cache.
2. To install `links2` package run in terminal `sudo apt-get install links2` (you can also use software center or synaptic package manager).
   In order to use it run `links2` command from terminal.

Comment: I think we have to enable universe repositories or something? Could you add that to the answer?

Comment: You are right. I always have universe repositories enabled so I didn't notice it.

Comment: Alright, answer is good now.